# Transferring Blob_values to a queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

I have trouble transferring the blob_name to my queue so I can read out the information there and process it. The information or content of the Blob is basically just a list of text (CSV). I also tried this with the blob_key, but both result in the same error.

```
# I create the blob - works fine, checked in Dashboard

    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/comma-separated-values',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename=str(datetime.now()))
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(low)
    files.finalize(file_name)


# Transferring the variables to the queue

    taskqueue.add(url='/filtering_brands', params={'filter_name' : filter_name, 'user' : user, 'lowkey' : file_name})

    self.redirect('/?sent=True')

class Queue(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

# Requesting the variables
    filter_name = self.request.get('filter_name')
    user = self.request.get('user')
    lowkey = self.request.get('lowkey')
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(lowkey)

# This is (apparently) the part that doesn't work
    low = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)

# Process the data and transfer it to an email script
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: object of type 'BlobReader' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot the specify the the blob_key name parameter.
Try this:

```
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(blob_key = str(lowkey))
```

Comment: get_blob_key() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blob_key' - Any ideas?